# I would like to get hibernate exception

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql

How do I generate this exception in hibernate pls

```
org.hibernate.MappingException stating that the Property maxindex does not exist in the collection
```

Comment: You would _like to get_ this exception??? Seriously?  Well, the message tells you what;s going wrong, so, I guess just do _that_.

Comment: @KevinAnderson I am serious

Comment: Just so we're clear: you're **not** asking "Please explain to me how did I get this exception and how may I avoid getting it in the future?". But you **are** asking, specifically, "How may I **intentionally cause this exception** to happen?"

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to know how do you generated the exception, not just to generate it. The message is pretty clear but, could you show your mapping? You can instruct Hibernate to create missing properties setting the hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property value to 'update':

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It sounds that it could be generated by using maxindex() function and we use it on collection indexed like Hashmap or array ...